# Python static methods definitions placing

Tags: python-3.x, conventions, pep8

I'm looking for a convention stating how different types of methods (i.e. `@staticmethod` or `@classmethod`) inside the Python class definition should be arranged. [PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008) does not provide any information about such topic.

For example, Java programming language has some [code conventions](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-141855.html#1852) referring to order in which static and instance variables are appearing in the class definition block. Is there any standard for Python 3 declaring such recommendations?

Answer (score 2):

The lack of answers so far just triggered me to simply write down the way I do it:

```
class thing(object):
        
    info = 'someinfo'
    # this can be useful to provide information about the class,
    # either as text or otherwise, in case you have multiple similar
    # but different classes.
    # It's also useful if there are some fixed numbers defining
    # the class' behaviour but you don't want to bury them somewhere
    # in the code (and haven't gotten around to putting them into
    # a separate file or look-up table, as you probably should)

    @staticmethod
    def stat(arg1, arg2):
        '''similarly, static methods are for stuff that is specific
        to the class but still useful without an instance'''
        pass
        # e.g.: some preprocessor for input needed to instantiate the
        # class, or a computation specific to the type of thing
        # represented by the class
        return(arg1 + arg2)

    @classmethod
    def classy(cls, str1)
        '''class methods get access to other class stuff. So, basically,
        they can do less-trivial things'''
        return(cls.stat(str1, cls.info)

    def __init__(self, arg):
        ''' ...and here starts the regular instance-internal stuff'''
        self.arg = arg

    def simplething(self, arg):
        '''I like to put the simple/basic things first which don't
        call other instance methods...'''
        return(arg * self.arg)

    def complicated(self, arg1, arg2):
        '''...before the methods which call the other methods above them'''
        return(self.simplething(arg1) / simplething(arg2))
```

In short: anything that is useful before the class has been created goes above the `__init__()` definition, first the class-global definitions, then static methods, then class methods, and after `__init__()`, all methods in a hierarchical order.

The benefit (to me) of doing it this way is that when I'm scrolling through the code and get to some method that calls other methods from the class, I've already seen those methods.
I suppose there is no objectively "best" way of doing this, since you could arrange things the other way round just as well and still know where to look first. To me, it makes more intuitive sense to me this way round. It also has the advantage that at some point during development, I'm more likely to add higher-level methods to the bottom than to squeeze low-level ones in at the top.

Another way to do it might be to sort things by "relevance". I.e.: The things which a user of the class is expected to need most often could be at the top. That might be good if you have lots of people using your code but not modifying it (much).
I do see some people organizing not their classes but modules of functions that way: The function you're most likely to call directly is at the top, and the function it calls are below. But for the internals of a class whose methods are rarely executed in order, that kind of order can be hard to determine and may make it harder to find the definite list of static or class methods.

...definitely not a standard, but maybe a little orientation for those looking for it, or at least a starting point to explain why your order is better than mine :)

Comment: This should be a PEP

Answer (score -1):

I think the way to declare `@staticmethod` and `@classmethod` on python is by adding that method statement (`@staticmethod` or `@classmethod`) directly above of your function.
  The usage of `@classmethod` is like instance function, it requires some argument like `class` or `cls` (u can change the parameter name so it's up to u).
 Whether for the `@static method`, it doesn't require self or class argument like instance method or class method. These two methods are bound to the class not to the object of the class so that `@staticmethod` cannot access or modify that because `@staticmethod` doesn't know about the state of the class, but for the `@classmethod` can access or modify class state because it has access into it (look at cls argument when calling `@classmethod`) but remember, if u are changing some state through `@classmethod`, It will change all the state of all instances of the class.
U can see the differences on the example below.

Example :

```
@classmethod
def something(cls, arg1, arg2, ....): #this is class method

@staticmethod
def something2(arg1, arg2, ...):   #this is static method
```

for further explanations, maybe you can see this links :
Static and class method explanation : [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/class-method-vs-static-method-python/)

Class or static variable explanation : [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/g-fact-34-class-or-static-variables-in-python/)

*I edited my answer because I seem not answer your question
There isn't any strict rules / standard to arrange it and luckily in python, u don't have to specify what types of method do u want to define (in java like public void ... or private int..., etc).

1. Name of Class

The first order comes the name of classes and then u can have attribute references and instantiation just like java. U can specify the scope of the attribute too (like private etc).

2. Instantiation

Then u can declare instantiation just like java by declaring `def __init__(self, ...)`. If u declare instantiation, then it will automatically invokes `__init__` when u declare new class instance. If u not declare this, python will keep to call this function because it automatically inherit from base class and won't do anything

3. Function / Method

After that, u can declare function. U can define `instance method` or `@classmethod` or `@staticmethod` and do something. Its method has its own advantages so it depends on how u need it.

Python supports inheritance and multiple inheritance too. 
For further explanation u can see this link [link](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html).

Hope it helps.

Comment: The question isn't about where the decorator goes to make a method a class or static method. The question is about how to order different method types in a class statement.